# Can't get image to be relative positioned

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't understand why is my figcaption not positioning correctly.

I have my image as **relative positioned**.

I have my figcaption as **absolute positioned**.

That means, the figcaption with a `bottom: 60px` should be at 60px from the images bottom.

But its not working, `figcaption` is getting the **window as relative**, and **not the image**.

**My view**

```
  <li class="item">
    <figure><%= image_tag photo.photo_url(:thumb), class: "spot-image" %>
        <figcaption class="spot-item-title">
            <h4><%= photo.title.truncate(30).downcase.capitalize %></h4>
            <span><%= photo.pins.count %> Productos etiquetados</span>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
   </li>
```

**My sass**

```
.item {
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include omega(3);
    background: $spot-bg;
    .spot-image {
        border: 4px solid red;
        position: relative;
    }
    .spot-item-title {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 60px;
    }
}
```

**CSS OUTPUT EDIT**

```
  .item {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.35765%;
    width: 23.23176%;
    background: #f3f3f3;


  .item .spot-image {
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid red;



  .item .spot-item-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;}
```

Comment: You might want to post your `span-columns` and `omega` mixins, or at least the resulting CSS.

Comment: _“That means, the figcaption with a bottom: 60px should be at 60px from the images bottom”_ – not, it does not; absolute positioning takes the next _ancestor_ element positioned with a value other then the default `static` as reference point; but your image is not an ancestor, but a mere _sibling_. Position the `figure` element relatively, if you want your caption to stay 60px from the bottom of that element.

Comment: @CBroe Bright answer. Didn't know that. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, I’ll make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 2):

> That means, the figcaption with a bottom: 60px should be at 60px from the images bottom

No, it does not; absolute positioning takes the next *ancestor* element positioned with a value other then the default `static` as reference point (or the viewport, if no such element exists); but your image is not an ancestor, but a mere *sibling*.

Position the `figure` element relatively, if you want your caption to stay 60px from the bottom of that element.